# In app purchase issues iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have tested in app purchase for a long time.
For testing in app purchase I have use TEST USER that I have crated in iTunes Conect.

But now when I try to sign in with my TEST USER account I get this message (before this message not appear)

[image]

So, this means that I have to enter all info about myself (bank account and etc). But I think for test user this items not needed.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Well yeah, a test user is for your own app, not for the actual Store..

Comment: thanks, yes I know about this, but now the store proposes to pass me the whole procedure as for the real user...

Comment: You should sign out from App Store account (in settings application) and sign in from within your application (it will ask you for usn/pwd when you will try to make a purchase). Also make sure that your test user account is valid or simply create a new one. There's no need for bank account and this stuff for test user. Just username, password, email (doesn't need to exist) and lost-pwd-Q&A)

Comment: yes thanks, I have created new test user and everything work good, but I don't now why previous test user not work. it work in previous month :) in this month it not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This often happens if you accidentally attempt to purchase real content with a test user. Try defining a new test user and deleting the old one.

Comment: I don't purchase real content. I think it comes from the fact that I'm trying to login to store settings. Now I try to sign out and make sing in directly in app. and this is work for me. but thanks a lot for your answer too.